# Modulate digital data into audio using AFSK

Tags: audio, audio-processing

I want to modulate digital data into audio. Then communicate it through any audio channel and demodulate at the destination from audio to data again. To do this I hope to use computer sound card and software modem without using any hardware implementation. In the internet, I found that this can be through the technique called Audio Frequency-Shift Keying(AFSK). I want to know that can I obtain bit rate more than 1200bps from AFSK and if it is no what the reason behind that this limitation.
Is there any technique efficient than AFSK for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

The most common currently-used form of AFSK is the [Bell202 modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_202_modem) at 1200 baud. There are a few other standards which also use 1200 baud, and some that run at less than 1200 bits per second, but none that I know of that run greater than 1200.

However, as far as I know, there's no reason you couldn't write a software modem to transmit and receive at a higher baud rate. Bell202 uses bit stuffing (allowing the data stream to use the same tone no more than 5 bits in a row) to help keep the transmitter and receiver from falling out of sync with each other, so a higher baud rate *might* require bit stuffing at a lower threshold (every 4 or 3 bits).

Another consideration is that the sound cards you're using should use a sampling rate equal to or a multiple of the baud rate you choose. This is one of the reasons 1200 baud is so common, as 1200Hz and 48000Hz are common sample rates with audio hardware.

So 1200 baud isn't a limit. It's just a standard.